# How to get webhook data in python

Tags: python, django, webhooks

I have a webhook url from messagebird, and post requests are being sent from the LINE Messaging API to that url when some events occur. I need to get the data of those webhooks (JSON data). I'm using Python (it's a Django app).

How can I get the data from the webhook?

Comment: You need to create a url in urls.py to handle the webhook call from messagebird, and define a view for it to do your logic, You need to configure somewhere it in messagebird, I believe you can configure it in  messagebird site after you logged in there. and afer the configuration, message bird will call the new url (may be a post request) once they completed their task

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Is there anyway I can test this in development? Still not in production

Comment: I believe you can  add more than one configuration in messagebird, one you can use it in dev and another in prod.